# Moving the "camera" of an HTML Canvas element

Tags: html, canvas, camera, offset, pan

I'm trying to find a clean way to "move the camera" of a canvas element.

This for my prototype game (side scroller). I'd love to think there's a better solution than moving the whole set of nodes to simulate a "camera" moving around.

Am almost certain to have read a simple how-to (using offsets?) but the fact I don't find anything like that starts to raise doubts... have I imagined reading that!?

Thanks to help me clarify...
J

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably you redraw your whole game scene 30 times a second (more or less)

You need to redraw your whole game scene but *first* translate the Canvas context by some offset.

`context.translate(x,y)` is precisely what you want. You'll want to read up on the use of that as well as the `save()` and `restore()` methods.

When you translate the context, everything drawn afterwards is shifted by that amount.

So you constantly draw something (maybe an enemy) at 50,50 using `drawImage(badguy,50,50)`. Then the player moves, which changes the `x` of `translate` to -1 (because the player is moving to the right) instead of 0. You still draw the enemy sprite with the command `drawImage(badguy,50,50)`, but when you draw it the enemy shows up as if it were at 49,50 because of the `context.translate(-1,0)` command shifting everything before its drawn.

Of course when you get into performance you'll want to be making sure that you are only ever drawing things that can actually be seen on the screen! If your are far down the level with `context.translate(-2000,0)`, you dont want to be drawing objects at 50,50 anymore, only ones that intersect the viewable area.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much... I started to think I imagined this translation stuff... Great :)

Comment: And for the performance thing, off-screen culling should be good in combination of clipping, thanks again!